# Tensorflow 2.x Java Bindings

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am reading this doc - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/package-summary

This page tells for TF 2.1.0 java binding is available , however when i check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow where can i find TF 2.1.0 java library ?

Answer (score 1):

The TF 2.x artifacts are still in development but available as snapshots artifacts and issued from [this new repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/java).

The API is close to TF 1.x but contains a few breaking changes too. As described in the README page of this repository, you can retrieve the artifacts by adding this to your dependencies:

For maven:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>tensorflow-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Example of dependency, see README.md for more options -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>tensorflow-core-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note that the version of the new TensorFlow for Java does not follow the version of TensorFlow itself, as it have a different release cycle. Currently, the snapshots are based on version TF2.2.0rc1.

Comment: Thank you for the reply , is there any sample inference code we can use in Java 2.x binding since API has changed ?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look at these Mnist examples [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/java-models/tree/master/tensorflow-examples/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/model/examples/mnist)

Comment: Thank you for reply , in TF 1.x I have java code doing inference as `Tensor x = Tensor.create(inputBytes,String.class); 
float[] y = sess.runner() .feed("input", x).fetch("output:0").run().get(0).copyTo(new float[1]);` 

In TF 2.x I converted as below `Tensor<TFloat32> y = sess.runner().feed("input", x) .fetch("output:0").run().get(0).expect(TFloat32.DTYPE);` but how to convert the x ?

Comment: I am basically trying to do inference on savedModel

Comment: The easiest way is to work with a `String` instead of byte arrays, so you can pass the input like this: `Tensor x = TString.scalarOf(new String(inputBytes))`. Otherwise, it is still possible to pass the bytes directly as follow: `Tensor x = TString.tensorOfBytes(NdArrays.scalarOfObject(inputBytes))`

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/java/issues/43 created issues we can discuss there .